# JQuery Hover and SlideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I wanted to make the navbar to stay displaying, not until i left my pointer hovered to that portion. What happens is that if I hover my pointer to the navbar, the display keeps getting toggled (displaying in then hiding.. it's on loop?) *I just want it to stay. Then hide again when my pointer left*

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $(".menu-trigger").hover(function(){
 
 $("li").slideToggle(400, function(){
  
  jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('show','');
 });
 
 }); 
}); 
</script>
```

```css
img {
 padding: 0px;
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: auto;
}

.menu-trigger {
 pointer: cursor;
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 font-family: Sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 background-color: #664c7d;
 height: 35px;
 width: 100%;
 
}
 li{
  display: none;
 }
 
li.navbar ul {
 }
}

div.nav-expanded {
 display: block;
 
}
```

Comment: Your code snippet has errors, please correct.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `.css('show': ' ')` ?

Comment: Removed unnecessary emotions from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few errors and it is not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish (`.css('show', '')`?).
I assume that what you need is an element that will toggle its class when hovered and will change back to its original state when it is not hovered anymore.
What you need to do, is toggle the class of your navigation bar every time your mouse goes over the element and out of it.

Assuming `$nav` is your navigation bar, you can use:

```
$nav.on('mouseover mouseout', function(){
  $nav.toggleClass('show');
});
```

Alternatively (and arguably safer):

```
$nav.on('mouseover', function(){
    $nav.addClass('show');
  }).on('mouseout', function(){
    $nav.removeClass('show');
  });
```

You can see usage in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8cq6uz4/5/).